# Ultraproduct question

Tags: logic

Prove that the ultraproduct of any infinite sequence of infinite
structures $(A_n : n ∈ N)$ with respect to an arbitrary ultrafilter U on $N$ is an
infinite structure.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: given any natural number $k$, find a statement which is true in a model if an only if that model has at least $k$ distinct elements. Show that this statement is true in all of those models $A_n$. Then use Łoś' Theorem.